# How can i sort this multidimensional array, that is sorted by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort this Array by ID.
This Code doesnt work:

```
    var arr = new Array();

    arr.push({
    id: "9",
    datum: "XXX",
    start: "XXX",
    ziel: "XXX",
    hinfahrt: "XXX",
    ruckfahrt: "XXX",
    zuzahlung: "XXX"
    });

    arr.push({
    id: "3",
    datum: "XXX",
    start: "XXX",
    ziel: "XXX",
    hinfahrt: "XXX",
    ruckfahrt: "XXX",
    zuzahlung: "XXX"
    });

    arr.push({
    id: "6",
    datum: "XXX",
    start: "XXX",
    ziel: "XXX",
    hinfahrt: "XXX",
    ruckfahrt: "XXX",
    zuzahlung: "XXX"
    });



    arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a[0] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    });

    console.log(arr);
```

Can someone help me with the sort. I tried the function sort, but nothing changed. I think i cant target the right area.
The Output shoud be like that.

```
{id: '3', datum: 'XXX', start: 'XXX', ziel: 'XXX', hinfahrt: 'on', …} 
{id: '6', datum: 'XXX', start: 'XXX', ziel: 'XXX', hinfahrt: 'on', …} 
{id: '9', datum: 'XXX', start: 'XXX', ziel: 'XXX', hinfahrt: 'on', …}
```

Comment: arr.sort((a,b)=>Number(a.id) - Number(b.id))

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of objects. It looks like you are trying to sort them by a property of those objects. You can access that property with dot notation. Try rewriting your sort like so:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.id === b.id) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (a.id < b.id) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the property directly with the delta of it.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: "9", datum: "XXX", start: "XXX", ziel: "XXX", hinfahrt: "XXX", ruckfahrt: "XXX", zuzahlung: "XXX" },{ id: "3", datum: "XXX", start: "XXX", ziel: "XXX", hinfahrt: "XXX", ruckfahrt: "XXX", zuzahlung: "XXX" },{ id: "6", datum: "XXX",  start: "XXX", ziel: "XXX", hinfahrt: "XXX", ruckfahrt: "XXX", zuzahlung: "XXX" }];

array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```